# update state of component for componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I am totally new in React, I am using one component, where I have condition. I want when it shows first it should show different message, but after that on button click it should show different values.

I understand that I can put it in `componentDidUpdate()` but I am also doing some manipulation of state in `componentDidMount()` so when I do refresh or first view page, `componentDidUpdate()` is also called. I just want on first view message has no change, but if on click

```
import React from 'react';

class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { message } = this.props
    this.state = {message: message}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      message: 'message set in didMount'
    }
   })  
    console.log(`componentDidMount called.`)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(`compoentDidUpdate called`)
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      message: 'new message'
    }
   })  
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>{this.state.message}</p>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `setState()` on the `componentDidMount()` you are in fact updating your state. So React re-renders your component and then calls `componentDidUpdate()`.

What you want to do is defining your initial state in your constructor. Because every `setState()` you do after the component is built, will force your component to re-render, meaning `componentDidUpdate()` will always get called afterwards.

Comment: What I want is when someone refresh page boolean 'refresh' is set to true, but when page load it become false and on all user interaction without refreshing it remain off, but when user refresh it become on? is it possible to do?